# ExecutorPlugin: plugin class bundled in app JAR, class not found on executor

Tags: apache-spark

### Summary

I tried creating an [ExecutorPlugin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ExecutorPlugin.html). I implemented my plugin class inside my app JAR and set `spark.executor.plugins` to the name of my plugin class. However, this doesn't work, and executors fail to start because they can't find the plugin class (ClassNotFoundException). The only way I got it to work is by passing my app JAR additionally as `spark.executor.extraClassPath`. Why is that the case? I would expect a class inside the app JAR to be visible to the executor. I would much prefer to be able to bundle the plugins inside my app JAR, to avoid using `spark.executor.extraClassPath`. Thanks!

### Details

Here is a very simple reproduction of the error. The plugin class:

```java
package spark_word_count;


public class SimplePlugin implements org.apache.spark.ExecutorPlugin {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

I compile an uberjar of my application, `spark-word-count.jar`, and submit like so using the spark-submit script:

```sh
spark-submit \
  --jars file:/mnt/jars/spark-word-count.jar \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --master spark://master:7077 \
  --conf spark.executor.plugins=spark_word_count.SimplePlugin \
  file:/mnt/jars/spark-word-count.jar \
  file:/data/hamlet.txt
```

### Errors from the Spark logs

Driver

```
19/10/28 19:29:35 ERROR [org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl] Lost executor 0 on 10.128.99.2: Unable to create executor due to spark_word_count.SimplePlugin
19/10/28 19:29:35 WARN [org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager] Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.128.99.2, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Unable to create executor due to spark_word_count.SimplePlugin
```

Executor logs

```
19/10/28 19:29:42 ERROR [org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend] Executor self-exiting due to : Unable to create executor due to spark_word_count.SimplePlugin
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark_word_count.SimplePlugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$loadExtensions$1(Utils.scala:2682)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.loadExtensions(Utils.scala:2680)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$executorPlugins$2(Executor.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.withContextClassLoader(Utils.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:221)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also I have confirmed that my uberjar contains the plugin class:

```
$ jar tf spark-word-count.jar | grep SimplePlugin
spark_word_count/SimplePlugin.class
spark_word_count/SimplePlugin.java
```

Comment: please add your code & error..

Comment: @SarathChandraVema I have added more details, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to one of the developers working on Spark plugins and got this helpful answer. Self-answering here for posterity:

> Hi,
>   Good point. I believe that using --jars for executor plugins works only for YARN (tested). It does not work for K8S either (tested). See also the comment on this matter related to recent work to extend plugin functionality for Spark 3.0: [apache/spark#26170 (comment)](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26170#issuecomment-546078368)

I looked a little deeper in the code of the Spark Executor class. The user's application JAR is only loaded at the time of launching the first *task*, by calling this `updateDependencies` method: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7955b3962ac46b89564e0613db7bea98a1478bf2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L375 whereas the plugins are resolved when the executor is constructed.